# In what library is strcat_s?

Tags: c, strcat-s

I tried including `string.h` and `stdlib.h`, but still get undefined reference compile errors.

This leads me to conclude that it is in a different library that I didn't include. Where is it?

I am using gcc compiler - the code is written in Windows, but is going to be compiled and run on a unix server.

Comment: Can your edit your post with what environment you are using (OS and compiler)?   Thanks.

Comment: Use `strcat` instead. There's no reason to use `strcat_s` except for making your code less portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an implementation in [slibc](https://code.google.com/p/slibc/).

Answer (score 9):

`strcat_s` can be found in `string.h` as of C 2011. Generally speaking, only microsoft has implemented these alternative functions.

Answer (score 4):

It is present in `string.h` on [windows platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx)

You can also refer this [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)

> Defined in header `<string.h>`

You can better use **[strcat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html)** if you are working on UNIX platform.

Comment: @Sunspawn:- You want to concatenate the strings...right? If yes then you can try like this: `String="$a $b $c"

where a="aaa"
b="bbb"
c="ccc"`

Comment: @Sunspawn:- You can also refer: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html

Comment: @RahulTripathi that's not C.

Comment: Look, I already have it in my code and I want it to work - is there a way to make it work or not?

Comment: @Sunspawn:- I dont think it will work in Unix platform. You can better try to use [strcat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) in UNIX

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is part of C11 standard:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/API02-C.+Functions+that+read+or+write+to+or+from+an+array+should+take+an+argument+to+specify+the+source+or+target+size

[image]

Honestly, I am not very well-versed with when it comes to standards and I can very well be wrong >.<